# R: frequency encoding for categorical variables via recipies package

Tags: r, r-recipes

I am looking for functionality similar to https://rdrr.io/github/bfgray3/cattonum/man/catto_freq.html

but implemented as a recipes::step_-function (https://tidymodels.github.io/recipes/reference/index.html)

Is anyone aware of an implementation for this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see [catto_freq](https://github.com/bfgray3/cattonum/blob/develop/R/freq.R) is doing count encoding similar to [CountEncoder in sklearn](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/count.html).

[Grouping is not supported by recipes right now](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/166). So, what you can do is count encoding with dyplyr and without recipes.

You can try two aproaches, but be aware of possible [data leakage](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/62836/frequency-count-encoding) in the first approach.

1. Using all the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

full <- read_csv("data/raw/train.csv")
new_data <- read_csv("data/raw/test.csv")
combined <- bind_rows(full, new_data)

combined_catto_freq <- combined %>%
  cattonum::catto_freq(Ticket)  %>%
  rename(Ticket_size = Ticket) %>%
  arrange(-Ticket_size )
combined_catto_freq

combined_mutate <- combined %>%
  group_by(Ticket) %>%
  mutate(Ticket = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rename(Ticket_size = Ticket) %>%
  arrange(-Ticket_size )
combined_mutate
```

2. Not using test data for the count encoding:

```
df2 <- full %>% 
  select(-Survived) %>% 
  cattonum::catto_freq(Ticket, test = new_data)
df2$train %>%
  rename(Ticket_size = Ticket) %>%
  arrange(-Ticket_size)
df2$test %>%
  rename(Ticket_size = Ticket) %>%
  arrange(-Ticket_size)

full_mutate <- full %>%
  group_by(Ticket) %>%
  mutate(Ticket_size = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(-Ticket_size )
full_mutate

new_data_mutate <- new_data %>%
 left_join(unique(select(full_mutate, Ticket, Ticket_size)), by = "Ticket")
new_data_mutate  %>%
  arrange(-Ticket_size)
```

PD: I used [titanic data](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic/data) for this example.